# Can we regard metric as the Higgs field of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, gravity

The longer version of the question is: should we regard special relativity just as a spontaneous symmetry breaking phase of general relativity, driven by the non-zero vacuum expectation value (VEV) of metric which is acting as the Higgs field of gravity.

---

A side note added after seeing the answer and references provided by @Mitchell Porter:
It seems that I am not the first one (too bad!) to investigate this idea of "metric as the Higgs field of gravity", though my version is a bit different since I am the first one (hopefully!) attempted to interpret the global Lorentz symmetry as similar to the *global $SU(2)$ custodial  symmetry* in electroweak theory. A few quotes from some renowned gauge gravity experts:

- *Trautman*: "The metric tensor is a Higgs field breaking the symmetry from $GL (4,R)$ to the Lorentz group" in [THE GEOMETRY OF GAUGE FIELDS](https://inspirehep.net/literature/150700)
- *Sardanashvily*: "If gravity is a metric field by Einstein, it is a Higgs field" in [Gravity as a Higgs field](https://inspirehep.net/literature/37958)

---

This post is related to another PSE question on [Gravity as a gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71476/gravity-as-a-gauge-theory/788701#788701). When gravity is expressed as a *local* Lorentz gauge theory (also know as Einstein-Cartan gravity), there are a lot of similarities compared with a typical gauge theory. For example, the gauge group of Lorentz gravity is the *local* Lorentz group $SO(1,3)$, and  the gauge field of Lorentz gravity is the spin connection field $\omega^{ab}_\mu$. However, the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ itself is not a gauge field in Lorentz gravity. Rather, the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$  is an add-on field in addition to the Lorentz gauge field $\omega^{ab}_\mu$ and there is no such add-on field in a typical gauge theory. Therefore, folks would usually point out that gravity, even in its Lorentz gauge theory format, is not comparable to a typical gauge theory.

But this point of view seems to be inaccurate. Let's take a look at the quintessential gauge theory: the electroweak theory of the standard model. Other than the electroweak gauge fields $W_\mu, A_\mu$, the electroweak theory has also an add-on non-gauge field: the Higgs field $H$ that are responsible for spontaneous symmetry breaking. Can we argue that metric is actually the Higgs field of gravity? Specifically, the symmetry-breaking add-on field of Lorentz gravity is the tetrad/veirbein field $e^a_\mu$ (which could be understood as the square root of metric $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{ab}e^a_\mu e^b_\nu$): the *non-zero* Minkowskian VEV of the tetrad/veirbein field
$$<0|e^a_\mu |0> = \delta^a_\mu$$
or equivalently
$$<0|g_{\mu\nu} |0> = \eta_{\mu\nu}$$
in Lorentz gravity breaks the gauge symmetry from the *local* Lorentz gauge symmetry $SO(1,3)$ down to the *global* Lorentz symmetry of special relativity, similar to the case of the *non-zero* VEV of Higgs field
$$<0|H |0> = v$$
in electroweak theory breaking the gauge symmetry from $SU(2)*U_Y(1)$ down to $U_{EM}(1)$.

So can we really regard metric as the Higgs field of gravity? For more discussions over the similarities and dissimilarities between metric and Higgs field, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71476/gravity-as-a-gauge-theory/788701#788701), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491621/could-there-exist-a-locality-field/491626#491626), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565412/covariance-in-special-and-general-relativity/565574#565574). See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502982/the-role-of-lorentz-tranformations/503119#503119) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620090/wave-function-in-geometric-algebra-rotors-and-electromagnetism/785629#785629) for discussions over the weird and peculiar state of *global* Lorentz symmetry as a combination of the residual elements from both the *local* Lorentz symmetry and the diffeomorphism symmetry, with tetrad/veirbein acting as the soldering form.

---

Added note to address @ACuriousMind comment:

The spontaneous symmetry breaking of the local Lorentz symmetry to global Lorentz symmetry is a complicated SSB process, which needs more explanation. To be exact, the standard model counterpart of the residual global Lorentz symmetry is actually not the electromagnetic $U_{EM}(1)$ symmetry. After spontaneous symmetry breaking, the residual *global* Lorentz symmetry in Lorentz gravity is more like the residual *global* $SU(2)$ custodial symmetry in electroweak theory. For how global custodial symmetry can survive SSB, please see details of *global* $SU(2)$ custodial symmetry in electroweak theory here: P. Sikivie, L. Susskind, M. B. Voloshin and V. I. Zakharov, Nucl. Phys. B 173 (1980) 189. Also see [Wikipedia page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custodial_symmetry) explaining custodial symmetry.

Comment: Deers and frogs have four legs, two eyes, etc... Are frogs the deers of ponds?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux, let's veer to zoology. Here is another observation in zoology: If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.

Comment: This makes no sense. You cannot actually spontaneously break gauge symmetries, cf. [Elitzur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%27s_theorem), [this P.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190416/50583), so the idea of breaking the "local symmetry" to the "global symmetry" cannot work.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, you are right. The SSB of the local Lorentz symmetry to global Lorentz symmetry is a subtle one, not elaborated in the original post for brevity purposes. The global Lorentz symmetry is more like the residual global $SU(2)$ custodial symmetry in electroweak theory. See details here: P. Sikivie, L. Susskind, M. B. Voloshin and V. I. Zakharov, Nucl. Phys. B 173 (1980) 189.

Comment: In the torsionless E-C theory, both the spin connection (massless gauge field) and the metric are functions of the Vierbeine, so it is not too meaningful to think of the latter as Higgs degrees of freedom.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, right, the spin connection and vierbein are related via the torsionless condition. Once the torsionless condition is relaxed (it's the equation of motion resulted from varying the E-C Lagragian with the spin connection provided there is no spin current), the the spin connection and vierbein are basically independent variables.

Comment: Except the spin connection is an *explicit function* of the Vielbeine! We are not on the same page.

Comment: @CosmasZachos to be fair, that doesn't need to be the case. OP is correct that when constructed as a gauge theory of the local Lorentz group, the gauge potentials $e_a$ and $\omega_{ab}$ are independent quantities. But I disagree on the rest of the interpretation following that.

Comment: There are plenty of models where gravity is associated with some kind of symmetry breaking, though not in the way suggested in the question. For example in MacDowell–Mansouri reformulation the $SO(1,4) $ symmetry breaks down to  $SO(1,3)$ giving rise to Einstein–Hilbert action with cosmological constant.

Comment: There is much to say with your comment (wich belongs to the philosophy realm) in response to mine, but unfortunately, there is not much space in the comments. With my first comment, I meant to say that you see similarities, ignore the differences, and then conclude with an equality of concepts. That's flawed reasoning. Responding to my analogy with your comparison, which is just a saying, is also flawed reasoning.

Comment: @A.V.S., yes, there are plenty of gauge gravity theories associated with symmetry breaking. Other than the MM $SO(1,4)$ theory, there is also for example an $SO(2,4)$ gauge gravity theory (https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.51.1674) breaking down to Einstein-Maxwell theory. As you have noted, the symmetry breaking of these are very different than tetrad/veirbein induced SSB as focused here in the current discussion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A version of this idea is discussed at the end of section 1.1.1 of

https://inspirehep.net/literature/1823987

which also cites the following as precursors

https://inspirehep.net/literature/150700

https://inspirehep.net/literature/37958

Comment: Thank you for providing the references! Could you please provide a summary of major points of these papers, and then I will accept the answer.

Comment: Not sure I have time!

Comment: Thanks anyway, accepted.

Comment: Please do not post links without at least a basic summary of what they contain and how that content answers the question, since link-only answers become useless if the link [rots away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Link-only answers are [not considered answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/859/50583) here and will be deleted. At the very least, mention the authors and titles of papers.

Answer (score 3):

We will be using Trautman's unifying formulation of both general relativity and Yang-Mills gauge theories as theories of a $G$-principal bundle $P\to M$ over spacetime $M$. For an exposition of this formalism, see [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/706483/50583). The Higgs part of this formalism is mostly from Trautman's *"The geometry of gauge fields"*.

**tl;dr:** The metric is formally analogous to a Higgs field, but there isn't a Higgs mechanism. The Lorentz group is fully analogous to the *unbroken* subgroup of the gauge group, not to a custodial symmetry.

A *Higgs field* is a field $\phi$ transforming in some associated bundle $V_\rho$ to some non-trivial representation $\rho$ of the gauge group whose equations of motion are
$$ V(\phi) = 0 \quad \land \quad \mathrm{d}_\omega \phi = 0,$$
where $V$ is some potential and $\mathrm{d}_\omega$ is the principal connection on our bundle. The solutions to $V(\phi) = 0$ form the *vacuum manifold* $\mathcal{V}$ and the group $G$ has a natural action on this space. If the action is transitive but not free, any point $\phi_0\in\mathcal{V}$ has a non-trivial stabilizer group $H:= \{g\in G \mid \rho(g)\phi_0 = \phi_0 \}$ and $\mathcal{V} = G/H$. In general, we need not necessarily assume transitivity and non-freeness and simply talk about $\mathcal{V}_{\phi_0}$ as the *orbit* of any field configuration $\phi_0$ under $G$.

Any $\phi_0$ allows for the reduction of the $G$-principal bundle to a $H$-principal bundle as the subbundle $P_{\phi_0} = \{ p\in P \mid \rho(p)\phi_0 = \phi_0 \}$. This is the *only* real mathematical reflection of the idea of symmetry breaking.

For the final discussion to make sense, we need to evade the deeply confusing issue of [Elitzur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%27s_theorem) that gauge symmetries *cannot be spontaneously broken*. For the "standard" resolution of this issue, see [this answer by Dominic Else](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203739/50583). We will use instead the idea of formulating the theory entirely in terms of gauge invariant fields from [*"Higgs Phenomenon without Symmetry Breaking Order Parameter"*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90448-X) by Fröhlich, Morchio and Strocchi:

For any $\mathcal{V}_{\phi_0}$ there are two options (see the paper for proofs of the following assertions):

- $H = \{1\}$ is trivial, the group acts transitively on $\mathcal{V}_{\phi_0}$. Then for any other field $\psi$ transforming in another $V_\sigma$, the space of fields $\psi : M\to V_\sigma$ is in bijection to fields $F(\phi)\cdot \psi$ where $F$ is a $\rho$-equivariant polynomial of $\phi$, the $\cdot$ represents a pairing between $V_\rho$ and $V_\sigma$ that results in a $G$-invariant scalar, and we say $F(\phi) = F'(\phi)$ if $F-F'$ vanishes on $\mathcal{V}_{\phi_0}$.
- $H$ is not trivial. Then $V_\sigma = \sum_i V_\sigma^i$ decomposes into representations $V_\sigma^i$ of $H$, and there are polynomials $F^i(\phi)$ valued in projections $V_\sigma \to V_\sigma^i$ in bijection to the projections $V_\rho \to V_\rho^i$. In this case any $\psi$ is in bijection to the set of fields $F^i(\phi)\psi$. $F^i(\phi)\psi$ is either gauge-invariant or transforms in $V_\sigma$ under the original gauge group.

The gauge-invariant ones are straightforwardly meaningful physical fields, while from the covariant ones we can construct invariant operators using Wilson lines. In any case, the masses of the Higgs mechanism just arise from plugging $\langle \phi_0\rangle$ into the terms of these fields that are still invariant or covariant under the full gauge group, there is no symmetry breaking in terms of these fields.

The metric in general relativity is now straightforwardly a Higgs field: It obeys the Einstein Field Equations $V(g) = 0$ with vacuum solution $g = \eta$, and the $\mathrm{d}_\omega g = 0$ is just the condition that the Levi-Civita connection is metric compatible (and in the Palatini formalism this is an equation of motion).

However, while this *does* produce a reduction of the structure group of the frame bundle to a $\mathrm{SO}(1,3)$-bundle (which purely comes about as the stabilizer of $\eta$), it does not "trigger" the Higgs mechanism: The whole reason that we in the above discussion care about constructing gauge-invariant quantities is that in Yang-Mills theories, they are pure internal gauge symmetries (see my answer from the beginning), while general relativity has no such internal symmetries - there is no pure gauge symmetry here that connects physically indistinguishable states, hence no need to introduce a Higgs-type reasoning.

So it depends very much on what we mean by a "Higgs field" in physical terms whether or not we really should call the metric that: If we just mean the *formal equivalence* to the Higgs fields of Yang-Mills theories, go ahead. If we are in danger of being misunderstood in the sense that its *physical effects* (i.e. the Higgs mechanism) are equivalent to that of a Yang-Mills Higgs field, we probably shouldn't say that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Agreed that there are both similarities and dissimilarities between metric and Higgs field, which is also discussed in a bit more detail here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71476/gravity-as-a-gauge-theory/788701#788701 and here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491621/could-there-exist-a-locality-field/491626#491626